# Handling nested case statements in Redshift

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, amazon-redshift

I am writing a Redshift query which require use of multiple case statements.

Pretext:
Customers can associated with more than one organizations like, sweet or salt etc.

Ask :
We have to check that customers associated with 'SWEETS' organization are picked first, if no affiliation with 'SWEETS' is available , than we have to take id of that organization where flag = 1.

I have to use a case statement in redshift to derive the result.

There are three different tables, customer table, organization  table and 3 table that determines how customers are associated with organization.

![enter image description here][1]

Code that I have tried is below , but after executing this , I am still getting the two organization ids, instead of one id which should be of sweet org.

```
SELECT customer_id
     , organization_id
FROM      customer_details  AS customer
LEFT JOIN organization      AS org
       ON customer.customer_id 
      AND organization_id = CASE WHEN organization_id IN (SELECT organization_id
                                                            FROM organization_type
                                                           WHERE organization_type = 'SWEET')
                                 THEN organization_id
                            ELSE org.organization_id END
```

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results as *text tables*.

Comment: case **expression**. Also: you don't need it here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select customer_id, organization_id
from (select c.customer_id, o.organization_id,
             row_number() over (partition by o.customer_id order by o.organization_type = 'SWEET' desc) as seqnum
      from customer_details c left join
           organization o 
           on c.customer_id = o.organization_id
     ) co
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Yes but what if there is no record for seqnum =1 , than ideally second organization id should be picked which has code as SALT.

Comment: @Dushala . . . There is ALWAYS are record for `seqnum = 1`.  If there is a SALT value, then that will be the one.  Otherwise, it will be something else.

Comment: Great, thanks. I solved the problem by introducing a temp table. In that table, first all the sweets records will go and their associated customers.. After that I used not in ('SWEET') and cust not in TEMP to insert those records for which customers are not yet populated and than I used the left join to expose organization id in my main code.